# Chance of a tie for most goals in a set of 4 football matches

Tags: poisson-distribution, ties

My statistics knowledge is basic at best but here goes:

4 football/soccer matches with expected goals of 2.6, 2.75, 2.4, 2.85

I'm interested in working out the probability of at least 2 of those games tieing to have the most goals out of the 4.

My thoughts were to use a poisson distribution to work out the chance of zero ties and take the inverse of that. But having set this up in excel, I'm coming out with a probability of greater than 1, so I'm obviously doing something wrong.

Apologies in advance if this is posted in the wrong place.

Comment: Could you clarify what "at least 2 of those games tieing to have the most goals" means?  Do you mean that two of the games are tied and the common number of goals exceeds the winning numbers in the other games?  Or perhaps that the winning scores are the same in at least two of the games?  Or something else?  And why are there only four expectations when *eight* teams would be involved in four matches?